# OpenCV hangs on read(), grab() etc from a file

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and g++.  I've also tried with python 2.7.8 and python 3.4.1.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  VideoCapture stream;
  if (argc > 1) {
    stream.open(argv[1]);
  } else {
    stream.open(0);
  }
  if (!stream.isOpened()) { 
    cout << "cannot open file";
  }

  while (true) {
    Mat frame;
    stream.read(frame);
    imshow("preview", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is compiled with:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o test test.cpp
```

Works just fine with the camera, but not when reading from a file the program just hangs.  Same is true with python.  Any ideas?

Comment: what is the format of file?If it is video file,it will work find but if it is jpg/png file better use Imread api : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Comment: I've tried both avi (the example tree.avi, along with another) and m2ts.  My suspicion is that this is somehow gstreamer related and not an opencv problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around to fixing this.  On Fedora 21 the opencv from the repository is built without ffmpeg support, because many codecs are not FOSS.  Compiling from source did the trick.